# Prevent Repeated Items by Title

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to prevent duplicated Items in a List. I Just don´t want that there are two Titles with the same Name.

The idea is doing it through a Content Editor using JavaScript (if it´s possible, of course) because I have no probability to deploy or to use SharePoint Designer.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the list settings and click on the Title column. In the settings of the title column, tick the Yes radio button for Enforce Unique Values.

This will give you the desired functionality.